# image in fixed size div and keep aspect by cropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a fixed size div (for example 300px X 300px) and I would like to display images from different sizes on the div and will fill the div completely and keep the image aspect by cropping the sides f the unfitted length.
The original picture is the bottom picture and the expected div image is the top image. [image: Example of the expected div and the original image]

Comment: Do you have your html and css code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about [supporting IE (Edge should get support soon)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit), `object-fit: cover` should do exactly what you want.  Then you can use `object-position` to position how it's cropped, though the default `center center` is probably what you would want for most cases.

[object-fit - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

[object-position - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)

If IE does matter (or you need Edge support now), then using a background image gets you access to [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) and [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) which allows you to do basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 div.container{
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-position: center center;
      border: 1px solid #333;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-image: url(https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/150592/150592,1233424894,3/stock-photo-beautiful-spring-flowers-24206422.jpg);">
</div> 
<br/>
<img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/150592/150592,1233424894,3/stock-photo-beautiful-spring-flowers-24206422.jpg"/>
```